# How can I cast a type as keyof T?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a type for a method argument that accepts either the name of an interface's property or an empty string. Here's what I've got:

```
type KeyofOrEmpty<T> = keyof T | '';

type CollapsibleKey<T,K extends KeyofOrEmpty<T>> = K extends '' ? T : T[K];
```

This appears to be doing what I want, except at `T[K]` the TS compiler complains that K can't be used to index T. That makes sense because '' isn't a valid index, but the ternary condition is already handling that case. What I want is just a cast to make it happy, but no amount of casting variants like `T[<keyof T>K]` or `T[K as keyof T]` seem to be legit syntax. What's the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an intersection type: `K & keyof T`.

An intersection type `A & B` is always assignable to both `A` and `B`, so the type `K & keyof T` is always assignable to `keyof T`.

Comment: Ok conceptually this makes sense, but I'm not seeing how to apply that with these generic constraints, ie., I can't see a way around the need to cast regardless. Could you provide a snippet?

Comment: You just write `T[K & keyof T]` instead of `T[K]`.